# For what Visual Studio generates database files automatically in C++ projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using C++ and SDL2 on Visual Studio 2015, but it generates automatically a database file (*.db) in the root of the solution (NameOfProject.VC.db)? What is its utillity? I already ereased this file and nothing has changed, but it is created again. Is there a way to set up Visual Studio to do not generate these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database is created to provide Intellisense (actions such as "Goto Definition" and auto-complete).

If you turn off Intellisense in the options, Visual Studio should stop recreating the database file.  But you should ask yourself again whether that small amount of disk space is worth the inconvenience of not having any advanced IDE features.

[image]

There are some additional database-related settings on that page as well.